# IText: How to add an inner table surrounded by text to a table

Tags: itext

I am trying to add a table surrounded by text to an outer table in iText 5.5.4, but the inner table disappears and I can't seem to fix the problem.

Here is what I am expecting:

```
*********************
* Hello World       *
* +++++++++++++++++ * <--
* + Goodbye World + * <-- these 3 lines never show up in the PDF
* +++++++++++++++++ * <--
* Hello World       *
*********************
```

Here is my code example:

```
public class TableTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException,     DocumentException {
        final Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 21, 21, 30, 35);
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("testTable.pdf"));

        document.open();

        // table 2
        final PdfPTable table2 = new PdfPTable(1);
        table2.setSpacingBefore(0);
        table2.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        table2.getDefaultCell().setBorderColor(BaseColor.RED);
        table2.getDefaultCell().setBorderWidth(1);

        table2.addCell("Goodbye World");

        // table 1
        final PdfPTable table1 = new PdfPTable(1);
        table1.setSpacingBefore(0);
        table1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        table1.setWidthPercentage(100);
        table1.getDefaultCell().setBorderColor(BaseColor.BLACK);
        table1.getDefaultCell().setBorderWidth(1);

        // contents
        Phrase phrase = new Phrase();

        phrase.add(new Chunk("Hello World"));
        phrase.add(table2); // <--- added but doesn't show up!
        phrase.add(new Chunk("Hello World"));

        table1.addCell(phrase);

        document.add(table1);

        document.close();
    }
}
```

This is part of a bigger report, and I am using the tables in this scenario for border and padding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using *text mode* (to be used when you only have text) in a situation where you should use *composite mode* (because you are adding a table to a cell).

Please take a look at the [`NestedTableProblem`](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/NestedTableProblem) example:

```
// table 2
final PdfPTable table2 = new PdfPTable(1);
table2.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
table2.getDefaultCell().setBorderColor(BaseColor.RED);
table2.getDefaultCell().setBorderWidth(1);
table2.addCell("Goodbye World");
// table 1
final PdfPTable table1 = new PdfPTable(1);
table1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
table1.setWidthPercentage(100);
// contents
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.setBorderColor(BaseColor.BLACK);
cell.setBorderWidth(1);
cell.addElement(new Chunk("Hello World"));
cell.addElement(table2);
cell.addElement(new Chunk("Hello World"));
table1.addCell(cell);
document.add(table1);
```

In this code snippet, the `cell` object is composed of different elements (that's what *composite mode* is about):

[image: Screen shot]

In your code snippet, you add several elements to a `Phrase` and you add this `Phrase` to a `PdfPCell` in *text mode*. As one element isn't ordinary text but a table, it can not be rendered.

Comment: This does solve the problem of the missing inner table, but it seems to add extra spacing between the top of the words and the borders compared to my original. Is "phrase.setLeading(fontSize)" the way to fix this?

Comment: Yes. In *composite mode*, you can change the leading of the elements (you'll need to replace the `Chunk` with a `Phrase` or a `Paragraph` to achieve this). Please try the methods `setUseAscender()` and `setUseDescender()` to adjust the space between the top / bottom line of text and the border. You can also change the padding of the `PdfPCell` if you think there's too much space between the text and the border.